# "Cannot index with multidimensional key" found in Pandas coding

Tags: python, pandas

Running the following code, an error was found in the second to last line:

> "buy_index=index_data[index_data['Close'] >
>   index_data['N1H'].shift(1)]"
>
> reading "ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key."

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas.io.data as web
import pandas as pd
symbol_list=['USB', 'AMGN','GS','BIIB', 'AGN']
N1 = 20
STOCK4 = web.DataReader(name= symbol_list,data_source='yahoo',start='2010-1-1')
index_data = STOCK4[['High','Low','Close']]
index_data['N1H']=pd.rolling_max(index_data['High'],N1)
index_data['N1H'].fillna(value=pd.expanding_max(index_data['High']), inplace=True)
buy_index=index_data[index_data['Close'] > index_data['N1H'].shift(1)]  ## an error
index_data.loc['buy_index'] = 1
```

Comment: This - `index_data['Close'] > index_data['N1H'].shift(1)` - seems to return a dataframe. Are you trying to get rows that have any value in the row as True?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to code a signal concerning Donchian Channel Breakout.

Comment: And `index_data` is a panel, are you looking for any particular dataframe in it?

Comment: Sorry, not so family with pandas, I can not distinguish between a panel and a dataframe. What I am trying to do is to get which stock in the symbol_list having an "Up breakout signal".

Comment: panel is like a collection of dataframes, a 3-d array.

Comment: So, should I try a loop or some other ways to filter the "Up breakout signal" stocks

Comment: I am not sure what *up breakout signal* stocks are. You should explain them in detail in your question.

Comment: IIUC does `buy_index=index_data[(index_data['Close'] > index_data['N1H'].shift(1)).index]` give you what you want?